# proxy with flutter using http package

Tags: flutter, http-proxy

I want to use Charles proxy to debug my requests made by Flutter using http package.

Dio is not an option because I want to export my requests from Postman that could be done only in Dart - http.

Is it possible to create a http client and pass proxy to it?

My current code is:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';

void main() async {
  String proxy = '192.168.0.103:8888';

  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();

  httpClient.findProxy = (uri) {
    return "PROXY $proxy;";
  };

  httpClient.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;

  final http = IOClient(httpClient);

  var headers = {
    'cookie':        'smth',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };
  var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('https://auth.my-domain.dev/account/login'));
request.bodyFields = {
    'ReturnUrl': 'data'
};
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
```

But there is an error here:

> The method 'Request' isn't defined for the type 'IOClient'.

This is because I am replacing http with IOClient but I don't know how to make a workaround.

UPDATE
Certainly I can make

```
final ioClient = IOClient(httpClient);
```

but after this I will have to do a lot of fixes. As I wrote earlier I am exporting my requests from Postman that could be done only in Dart - http.
And by using IOClient I will have to fix a lot:

replace

```
var request = ioClient.post(Uri.parse('https://auth.dev-drive.dodois.dev/account/login')`);
```

with

```
var request = ioClient.post(Uri.parse('https://auth.dev-drive.dodois.dev/account/login'));
```

and

```
request.bodyFields
//The setter 'bodyFields' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Response>
```

and

```
request.headers.addAll(headers);
//The getter 'headers' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Response>'.
```

and

```
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
//The method 'send' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
```

and do it with every request. And there a lot of them.

Comment: You are using the characters `http` in two places - once as the `as http` and once as `final http = IO...` and getting confused which is which. Change one: `final ioClient = IOClient...`

Comment: Done, but what should I do to do my requests via it?

Comment: `await ioClient.post(...)` See: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseClient/post.html

Comment: edited my initial post

Comment: change `var request = ioClient.post` to `final response = await ioClient.post`

Comment: @Kosh are you able to manage settings proxy with 'http' package ?? Please let me know.